# Two circuits with Toffoli, Hadamard and Rx gates

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, programming

Can anyone explain me the behaviour of these two circuits? They contain Hadmard and rotation gates before the Toffoli gate.

[image]

Results of simulation:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! What's your question? As you said, between the barriers you have a toffoli. It looks like more context can help with an explanation.

Comment: @luciano Thank you, I just saw a question containing this circuits, unfortunately I don't have more context, only I can provide the simulation result for circuits

Comment: In a notebook code *__*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In the first circuit** after Hadamard gates (I suppose that initial state is $|000\rangle$ and I will use Qiskit's convention for labeling the qubits $|q_2 q_1 q_0 \rangle$):

$$|000\rangle \xrightarrow[]{\text{Hadamards}} \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle(|00\rangle + |01\rangle+|10\rangle + |11\rangle)$$

The $R_x(0) = I$, so it does noting. Then comes Toffoli gate (apply $X$ gate on the $q_2$ qubit if the other two (control qubits) are in $|1\rangle$ state):

$$\xrightarrow[]{\text{Toffoli}} \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle(|00\rangle + |01\rangle+|10\rangle) + \frac{1}{2}|111\rangle$$

**In the second circuit** $R_x(\pi) = -iX$ (we can neglect $-i $ term because it is a global phase here) and the combained action of Hadamards plus $R_x(\pi)$

$$|000\rangle \xrightarrow[]{\text{Hadamards + }R_x(\pi)} \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle(|00\rangle + |01\rangle+|10\rangle + |11\rangle)$$

Then Toffoli:

$$\xrightarrow[]{\text{Toffoli}} \frac{1}{2} |1\rangle (|00\rangle + |01\rangle+|10\rangle) + \frac{1}{2}|011\rangle$$

Comment: No Thank you this is what i'm looking for, but dose your calculation now confirms the simulation or I have trouble reading simulation result!? Because in first case I don't see the '100'

Comment: Or in the second case we don't have '111'

Comment: @Farhad, I edited the answer, the problem was with the labeling convention...Qiskit uses this labeling convention in ket vectors $|q_2 q_1 q_0\rangle$ rather than $|q_0 q_1 q_2\rangle$ that I was using initially.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: @Farhad, you are welcome :). I just want to suggest to rename the question with this title "Two circuits with Toffoli, Hadamard and $R_x$ gates". I think this title better describes the question.